# Is there more than one invisibility cloak?

Tags: harry-potter, invisibility-cloak

In *HP and the Philosopher's Stone*, Harry gets an invisibility cloak as a Christmas present from Dumbledore. (His father had owned it before.)

As soon as Ron saw it, he recognised it to be as an invisibility cloak (which we later get to know is one of the deathly hallows), and he says they are incredibly rare.  Which indicates that there has been more than one IC in the Potterverse.  Is it mentioned anywhere in the books or movies about any other invisibility cloak? If yes then how do they work? And are they as effective as the one with Harry? Please give a canon answer.

Comment: Copy/paste = rep - http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Invisibility_cloak

Comment: I've downvoted for lack of research effort. A [simple google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Is+there+more+than+one+invisibility+cloak%3F&oq=Is+there+more+than+one+invisibility+cloak%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.778j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for the title of your question leads to no less than 18 pages that answer this in the first 20 results.

Comment: Read the complete series once, you will get your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How Harry's invisibility cloak works is a mystery, but it lasts forever, unlike other "regular" invisibility cloaks, where the invisibility wears off after some time or the fabric will wear and rip. So no, they're not as effective as Harry's.

They can work in different ways. Either they're simply enchanted cloaks with charms that make them invisible, or they can be made of hair from a creature called the Demiguise, which has the ability to turn invisible (this is mentioned by Xenophilius Lovegood, and a Demiguise appears in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*).

Other specific invisibility cloaks are mentioned. Barty Crouch Jr was hidden under one when his father smuggled him out of Azkaban, for example.

Comment: You get thumbs up from me for taking the time to answer stupid questions

Comment: @MatrimCauthon :)

Answer (score 1):

In GOF, Moody himself has 2 invisibility cloaks.
And Fred and George make invisible stuffs like hat and cloak.

For how they work:
Seeing them Hermione suggested there must be a charm which extends the field of invisibility. So there is a charm to make them work for invisibility.